# Multiple select with filtering and select all

Tags: forms, selection, multi-selection

I have an issue regarding UX for a popup that allows selection of multiple items with filtering. This is the current one present in the application :

[image: Existing product selection popup]

[image: Existing product selection popup clicked]

Users wanted to be able to select all elements (or all filtered elements in the list). This was the given suggestion but I am not a fan, is there a way to mix both or have an entirely new more appropriate solution ?

[image: Suggested product selection popup]

Answer (score 0):

I also believe that you can take the best of both worlds. Which is a concept of a expandable list of checkboxes with the first one being `Select All`.

I would also suggest moving the selected tokens (of the first image) inside the Searchbar instead of under it as the selections get hidden by the list as it seems in the second image.

These can be pretty easily adjusted in the mockups or even in the code so you can suggest multiple scenarios that you believe can improve the current issue.

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use left to right solution on left side you have available product name & on right side selected product name one user on right side available product name checkbox it will completely  move to the right side selected product section with close button.

Comment: this treatment can be done if you have single dropdown only. showing upfront data make good user experience.